# AWS OpsWorks Deployment Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I've been using AWS OpsWorks for a couple months and have had no problems deploying my app from my GitHub repo for the past 2-3 months, but when I went to deploy again today (the same way I've always been), it failed during the `deploy` command.

[image]

I checked my log files and it looks like there's a problem with a Shell Command failing. I'm unsure of what exactly is going on here, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my Logfile from the deployment:

```
[2016-05-28T17:33:06+00:00] INFO: AWS OpsWorks instance 68c2a91e-635b-4e1f-a71e-0e19c2d4b86c, Agent version 3437-20160504095744
[2016-05-28T17:33:08+00:00] INFO: Starting chef-zero on port 8889 with repository at repository at /opt/aws/opsworks/current
One version per cookbook
data_bags at /var/lib/aws/opsworks/data/data_bags
nodes at /var/lib/aws/opsworks/data/nodes

[2016-05-28T17:33:08+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2016-05-28T17:33:08+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 ***

***** (I Cut out the middle non-important stuff here from my Logfile because it was taking up too much text and I was unable to post the question) *****

[2016-05-28T17:33:33+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] cloning repo git@github.com:thomasbaldwin/apollo.git to /srv/www/apollo/shared/cached-copy
[2016-05-28T17:33:33+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] checked out branch: HEAD onto: deploy reference: 3502ba1a989582c9a05ee89bf7a70704def75811
[2016-05-28T17:33:33+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] synchronizing git submodules
[2016-05-28T17:33:33+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] enabling git submodules
[2016-05-28T17:34:08+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set user to deploy
[2016-05-28T17:34:08+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set group to apache
[2016-05-28T17:34:08+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] copied the cached checkout to /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set user to deploy
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set group to apache
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] running callback before_migrate
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] created directories before symlinking: tmp,public,config
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] linked shared paths into current release: system => public/system, pids => tmp/pids, log => log
[2016-05-28T17:34:39+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] made pre-migration symlinks
[2016-05-28T17:35:10+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set user to deploy
[2016-05-28T17:35:10+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] set group to apache
[2016-05-28T17:35:10+00:00] INFO: package.json detected. Running npm install --production.

================================================================================
Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'deploy[/srv/www/apollo]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '228'
---- Begin output of sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 ----
STDOUT: npm WARN package.json Apollo@0.1.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/lodash/3.5.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.12
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
npm ERR! path /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_keyof.js
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! errno -28

npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC, open '/srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_keyof.js'
npm ERR! nospc This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/npm-debug.log
STDERR: 
---- End output of sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 ----
Ran sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 returned 228


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/libraries/shellout.rb:9:in `shellout'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_nodejs/libraries/nodejs_configuration.rb:6:in `npm_install'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:151:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb

65:     deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
66:       provider Chef::Provider::Deploy.const_get(deploy[:chef_provider])
67:       keep_releases deploy[:keep_releases]
68:       repository deploy[:scm][:repository]
69:       user deploy[:user]
70:       group deploy[:group]
71:       revision deploy[:scm][:revision]
72:       migrate deploy[:migrate]
73:       migration_command deploy[:migrate_command]
74:       environment deploy[:environment].to_hash
75:       purge_before_symlink(deploy[:purge_before_symlink]) unless deploy[:purge_before_symlink].nil?
76:       create_dirs_before_symlink(deploy[:create_dirs_before_symlink])
77:       symlink_before_migrate(deploy[:symlink_before_migrate])
78:       symlinks(deploy[:symlinks]) unless deploy[:symlinks].nil?
79:       action deploy[:action]
80: 
81:       if deploy[:application_type] == 'rails' && node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('rails-app')
82:         restart_command "sleep #{deploy[:sleep_before_restart]} && #{node[:opsworks][:rails_stack][:restart_command]}"
83:       end
84: 



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:65:in `block in from_file'

deploy("/srv/www/apollo") do
params {:deploy_data=>{"deploy_to"=>"/srv/www/apollo", "chef_provider"=>"Timestamped", "keep_releases"=>5, "current_path"=>"/srv/www/apollo/current", "document_root"=>"", "ignore_bundler_groups"=>["test", "development"], "absolute_document_root"=>"/srv/www/apollo/current/", "rake"=>"/usr/local/bin/rake", "migrate"=>false, "migrate_command"=>"if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi", "rails_env"=>"production", "action"=>"deploy", "user"=>"deploy", "group"=>"apache", "shell"=>"/bin/bash", "home"=>"/home/deploy", "sleep_before_restart"=>0, "stack"=>{"needs_reload"=>false}, "enable_submodules"=>true, "shallow_clone"=>false, "delete_cached_copy"=>true, "purge_before_symlink"=>["log", "tmp/pids", "public/system"], "create_dirs_before_symlink"=>["tmp", "public", "config"], "symlink_before_migrate"=>{"config/opsworks.js"=>"opsworks.js"}, "symlinks"=>{"system"=>"public/system", "pids"=>"tmp/pids", "log"=>"log"}, "environment"=>{"RAILS_ENV"=>nil, "RUBYOPT"=>"", "RACK_ENV"=>nil, "HOME"=>"/home/deploy", "NODE_ENV"=>"production", "S3BUCKET"=>"apollo-cdn", "PLATFORM_APPLICATION_ARN"=>"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:007683507359:app/APNS/Apollo_Prod"}, "environment_variables"=>{"NODE_ENV"=>"production", "S3BUCKET"=>"apollo-cdn", "PLATFORM_APPLICATION_ARN"=>"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:007683507359:app/APNS/Apollo_Prod"}, "ssl_support"=>false, "auto_npm_install_on_deploy"=>true, "nodejs"=>{"restart_command"=>"monit restart node_web_app_apollo", "stop_command"=>"monit stop node_web_app_apollo", "port"=>80}, "application"=>"apollo", "application_type"=>"nodejs", "auto_bundle_on_deploy"=>true, "deploying_user"=>"arn:aws:iam::007683507359:root", "domains"=>["apollo"], "mounted_at"=>nil, "restart_command"=>"echo 'restarting app'", "ssl_certificate"=>nil, "ssl_certificate_key"=>nil, "ssl_certificate_ca"=>nil, "scm"=>{"scm_type"=>"git", "repository"=>"git@github.com:thomasbaldwin/apollo.git", "revision"=>nil, "ssh_key"=>"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\neHTnzSZwJegF6gkoEf6wfyKlkH4W98xvv8k2rLRGToPEhT1D9/E2+b4FxYE=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "user"=>nil, "password"=>nil}, "database"=>{"host"=>"apollo-rds-instance.cbl4aupzibte.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "database"=>"apollo", "port"=>3306, "username"=>"thomasbaldwinj", "password"=>"91zFzVoh", "reconnect"=>true, "data_source_provider"=>"rds", "type"=>"mysql"}, "memcached"=>{"host"=>nil, "port"=>11211}}, :app=>"apollo", :name=>nil}
provider Chef::Provider::Deploy::Timestamped
action [:deploy]
updated true
updated_by_last_action true
retries 0
retry_delay 2
deploy_to "/srv/www/apollo"
environment {"RAILS_ENV"=>nil, "RUBYOPT"=>"", "RACK_ENV"=>nil, "HOME"=>"/home/deploy", "NODE_ENV"=>"production", "S3BUCKET"=>"apollo-cdn", "PLATFORM_APPLICATION_ARN"=>"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:007683507359:app/APNS/Apollo_Prod"}
repository_cache "cached-copy"
purge_before_symlink ["log", "tmp/pids", "public/system"]
create_dirs_before_symlink ["tmp", "public", "config"]
symlink_before_migrate {"config/opsworks.js"=>"opsworks.js"}
symlinks {"system"=>"public/system", "pids"=>"tmp/pids", "log"=>"log"}
revision "HEAD"
remote "origin"
enable_submodules true
scm_provider Chef::Provider::Git
keep_releases 5
enable_checkout true
checkout_branch "deploy"
cookbook_name "deploy"
recipe_name "nodejs"
repo "git@github.com:thomasbaldwin/apollo.git"
user "deploy"
group "apache"
migration_command "if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi"
before_migrate #<Proc:0x0055b12a6113a0@/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:100>
shared_path "/srv/www/apollo/shared"
destination "/srv/www/apollo/shared/cached-copy"
current_path "/srv/www/apollo/current"
end



[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] ERROR: deploy[/srv/www/apollo] (deploy::nodejs line 65) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '228'
---- Begin output of sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 ----
STDOUT: npm WARN package.json Apollo@0.1.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/core-js/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/deploy/.npm/lodash/3.5.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.12
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
npm ERR! path /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_keyof.js
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! errno -28

npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC, open '/srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_keyof.js'
npm ERR! nospc This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/npm-debug.log
STDERR: 
---- End output of sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 ----
Ran sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333 && npm install --production' 2>&1 returned 228
[2016-05-28T17:36:48+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual underlying error is this one:

```
npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC, open '/srv/www/apollo/releases/20160528173333/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_keyof.js'
npm ERR! nospc This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system.
```

Your disk drive is full.

Comment: Thomas: maybe you should setup alerts for disk full?

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply I didn't see this! I ended up figuring this out and upgraded to a t2.medium server and it worked no problem, but I've been getting the issue with that size server too now, but I haven't really changed anything other than adding a couple extra lines of couple. Any ideas?

Comment: @chicks is disk full the same thing as me needing to upgrade my server to a bigger size?

Comment: No!  Often you can delete some log files or something else that you don't want anymore and keep the same instance size.  But sometimes the disk full alert will lead to throwing more resources at the problem.